# Infinitely recursive lazy sequence appears as empty sequence in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Suppose I wrote:

```
(def stuff
  (lazy-seq stuff))
```

When I ask for the value of `stuff` in REPL, I would expect it to be stuck in an infinite loop, since I'm defining `stuff` as itself(which pretty much says nothing about this sequence at all).

However, I got an empty sequence instead.

```
> stuff
()
```

Why?

---

Edit: By "recursive" I meant recursive data, not recursive functions.

I'm still confused about why the sequence terminated. As a comparison, the following code *is* stuck in infinite loop(and blows the stack).

```
(def stuff
  (lazy-seq (cons (first stuff) [])))
```

---

Some background: This question arises from me trying to implement a prime number generator using the sieve of Eratosthenes. My first attempt was:

```
(def primes
  (lazy-seq (cons 2
                  (remove (fn [x]
                            (let [ps (take-while #(< % x) primes)]
                              (some #(zero? (mod x %)) ps)))
                          (range 3 inf))))) ;; My customized range function that returns an infinite sequence
```

I figured that it would never work, since `take-while` would keep asking for more primes even if they could not be calculated yet. So it surprised me when it worked pretty well.

```
> (take 20 primes)
(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71)
```

Comment: it couldn't produce infinite loop, since there is no function call there. what would produce an infinite loop as expected is `(defn stuff [] (lazy-seq (stuff)))`

Comment: @leetwinski It is possible to produce an infinite loop with only lazy sequences. See my edits.

Comment: `take-while` is limited by x, and x is a current primes 'cap', so it will never ask for more primes over the ones that are already generated. Also `range` already produces infinite seq, no need to customize it. `(drop 3 (range))`, or `(iterate inc 3)`

Comment: but you would be surprised that `take-while` is not even needed here: `(fn [x] (some #(zero? (mod x %)) primes))`. and even without `lazy-seq`: `(def primes
  (remove (fn [x] (some #(zero? (mod x %)) primes))
          (iterate inc 2)))`

Comment: @leetwinski It works, but why? Say we need to check if 5 is a prime. Wouldn't `some` iterate though all the primes(including 5 itself?) and check if any of them is a divisor?

Comment: The point is that inside remove predicate `primes` is seen as 'primes-by-far'. You can see it by printing out primes value. I guess looking at the clojure source would tell you more on lazy seq semantics, than I can do now ))

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/30a36cbe0ef936e57ddba238b7fa6d58ee1cbdce/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java) of LazySeq, you can see that `(def stuff
  (lazy-seq (cons (first stuff) [])))` causes a stack overflow because when you try to realize the `lazy-seq`, you need to first evaluate `(first stuff)` which itself requires realizing the lazy sequence. This leads to an infinite recursion, which blows the stack. This is not an issue for `(def stuff (lazy-seq stuff))` because calling `(fn [] stuff)` doesn’t realize `stuff`.

Comment: @YizheSun I looked into why @leetwinski's definition for `primes` works and wrote about it in a blog post: https://phillippe.siclait.com/blog/primes-lazy-sequence

Answer (score 6):

First, each lazy seq can only be realized once. Second, your definition of `stuff` doesn't use recursion — `stuff` isn't a function. If you look at the [definition](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/38bafca9e76cd6625d8dce5fb6d16b87845c8b9d/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L683) of `lazy-seq`, you can see that your definition of `stuff` expands to

```clj
(def stuff (new clojure.lang.LazySeq (fn* [] stuff)))
```

When the `fn` arg to the `clojure.lang.LazySeq` constructor is invoked, it returns the same lazy seq that has already been realized. So, when you attempt to print the lazy seq to the REPL, iteration immediately terminates and returns nil.

You can verify that the type of `stuff` is `clojure.lang.LazySeq`

```
user=> (type stuff)
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

and that after printing `stuff` to the REPL, `stuff` has been realized

```
user=> (realized? stuff)
false
user=> stuff
()
user=> (realized? stuff)
true
```

You can use recursion to get the effect that you expected

```
user=> (defn stuff
         []
         (lazy-seq (stuff)))
#'user/stuff
user=> (stuff) ;; Hangs forever.
```

Comment: When was `stuff` realized for the first time? And what was the value? Also see my edits.

Comment: `stuff` is realized when you send the symbol to the REPL, because to print the LazySeq, its `seq` method is called. The value of `stuff` is an instance of `clojure.lang.LazySeq`. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/30a36cbe0ef936e57ddba238b7fa6d58ee1cbdce/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java) for LazySeq, you can trace the logic. After `seq` is called, all of the Java object’s fields are null. It appears as an empty sequence in the REPL because that's how `print-method` is defined for objects `x` which implement `ISeq` where `(seq x)` is nil.